# why does adding a NavLink to my navbar completely destroy my react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar

i have a well-functioning site, and i want to add active link highlighting to my navbar. every tutorial i've seen says to use NavLink, but when I add a NavLink to my Navbar.js file, the entire site (even other pages) just turns into a blank white screen.

how do i fix this? i've included some of my code below

**NavBar.js**

```js
import '../styles/Navbar.css';
import React, { useCallback, NavLink } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Navbar() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleHome = useCallback(() => navigate('/', {replace: true}), [navigate]);
  const handleContribute = useCallback(() => navigate('/contribute', {replace: true}), [navigate]);
  const handleAbout = useCallback(() => navigate('/about', {replace: true}), [navigate]);
  const handleContact = useCallback(() => navigate('/contact', {replace: true}), [navigate]);

    return (
        <div id = "navbar">
          <div id = "fourth"><button onClick = {handleHome}>Home</button></div>
          <div id = "fourth"><button onClick = {handleContribute}>Contribute</button></div>
          <div id = "fourth"><button onClick = {handleAbout}>About</button></div>
          <div id = "fourth"><button onClick = {handleContact}>Contact</button></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**App.js*

```js
import '../styles/App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { React, useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Home from "./Home";
import Contribute from "./Contribute";
import About from "./About";
import Contact from "./Contact";
//there's more imports here, but i won't include them on this post because they're not relevant
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  })
  return (
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path = "/" element = {<Home />}/>
          {/*french*/}
          <Route path = "/frenchi" element = {<FrenchI />} />
          <Route path = "/frenchii" element = {<FrenchII />} />
          <Route path = "/frenchiii" element = {<FrenchIII />} />
          <Route path = "/frenchiv" element = {<FrenchIV />} />
          {/*german*/}
          <Route path = "/germani" element = {<GermanI />} />
          <Route path = "/germanii" element = {<GermanII />} />
          <Route path = "/germaniii" element = {<GermanIII />} />
          <Route path = "/germaniv" element = {<GermanIV />} />
          {/*latin*/}
          <Route path = "/latini" element = {<LatinI />} />
          <Route path = "/latinii" element = {<LatinII />} />
          <Route path = "/latiniii" element = {<LatinIII />} />
          <Route path = "/latiniv" element = {<LatinIV />} />
          <Route path = "/contribute" element = {<Contribute />} />
          <Route path = "/about" element = {<About />} />
          <Route path = "/contact" element = {<Contact />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  );
}
```

**Screenshots**
[here is the website WITHOUT test in Navbar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZyvZ.jpg)

[here is the website WITH test in Navbar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8MWV.jpg)

Comment: The `react` package does not export a `NavLink` named export. It's not clear what such a component would do, either. You might need to go back to wherever you learned that and review more closely, or find a different approach.

Comment: i believe it does, otherwise i would be receiving an error of "NavLink" undefined, but i am not. is there another package from which is should import NavLink?

Comment: Perhaps the `react-router-dom` package you are using or [React Router](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)?